# How to reduce the height of androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have trouble with reducing the height of the `OutlinedTextField` in compose. I am trying to do a SearchBar inside the `TopAppBar` like it is done in many google apps(Gmail,Play Store). I am unable to achieve this in material3.

I tried copying the `OutlinedTextField` and making my own custom view but it is too much stuff that I would have to copy, so I think there should be a better way.

Edit: The TextFiled should also have a leadingIcon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OutlinedTextField` follows the material guidelines. If you want to change the height you can use **`BasicTextField`** applying the `height` modifier adding the **`OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox`**.

Something like:

```
BasicTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(36.dp),
    singleLine = singleLine,
    interactionSource = interactionSource
) { innerTextField ->
    TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
        value = text,
        innerTextField = innerTextField,
        enabled = enabled,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Add, "contentDescription",
                modifier = Modifier.clickable { /* doSomething */ }
            )
        },
        contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithoutLabelPadding(
            top = 0.dp,
            bottom = 0.dp
        )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: That works well for a normal TextFiled, but I also want to add a leadingIcon which again ruins the height even when using  `LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false`.

Comment: @kacsagit what height are you using? I've tried to add the icon using the leadingIcon attribute (check the updated answer) and it still works well.

Comment: Okay, I found that the `.height(36.dp)` is a crucial part it was not enough to just use ` .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 0.dp)`